# displaying most popular form submissions?

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, search

I have a site built for disabled students to search YouTube and then displays the results in an accessible format.

I want to display the top 5 most popular searchterms used exclusively on this site.

Search terms are submitted using a text input form - is there a way to also submit the searchterms to mysql and then display the most popular?

Or a better method?

Form submit code:

```
<fieldset class="search"> 
<form method="get" name="search" action="<?php echo 
 htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
  <input type="text" label="type here" class="box" name="v" placeholder="type here..."/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>  
</form>
    </fieldset>
```

Many thanks, Mike

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way would be to create a database table that saves searchterms (convert to lowercase with strtolower() and check whether the term has already been saved) and a simple INT field that you increment if the search term already exists in your database.

Now you can select the most popular search terms from the database with a query like:

```
SELECT `term` FROM `search_terms` ORDER BY `search_count` DESC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

One other possible idea (which might be silly, I'm not sure) : you could add two MySQL tables, one for SearchTerms (with e.g. columns SearchTermID (a number), and a string for the SearchTerm), and then a table of Searches, which has a SearchID, a SearchTermID (which is attached to the SearchTerms table using the SearchTermID column, and e.g. SearchDateTime to record when the search happened). Then every time someone searches, check the SearchTerms table to see if this term has been searched for before, and if so, add a record to the Searches table.

Then you could have a query to do "return me the top 5 SearchTerms that have been used this week" by something like
`SELECT SearchTerm,Count(SearchID) FROM SearchTerms INNER JOIN Searches ON Searches.SearchTermID=SearchTerms.SearchTermID WHERE SearchDateTime > [today minus a week, or something] LIMIT 5`

I'm not sure which would be good indexes, but I think one on SearchDateTime would be useful for the "top 5" query. And one on the string in SearchTerms too since  you'll be checking that column when recording searches.

(Maybe it would also be good to have a NumberOfTimesSearched column in the SearchTerms table, but you can always calculate it by adding up the number of times the relevant SearchTermID appears in the Searches table)